# Issue with emptying class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to empty the .scrolling-box class when a user enters something in a search bar. When I run it the class empties for a split second but then everything reappears and I can't figure out why?
This is the code I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchbutton').click(function(){
            displayHotels();
        });
        function displayHotels(){
            var location = $('#searchbar');
            location.focus();
            if(location.val() != ""){
                $('.scrolling-box').empty();
            }
        }
});
```

Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="firstBar">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="searchbar">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchbutton">Search</button>
            </form>

            <div class="scrolling-box">
                <img src="review1.jpg" alt="review1">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: add your ```HTML``` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you button type is submit and when form submits, page will relaod. so use `event.preventDefault()`  to prevent the page reload on button click event.
You can also fix this by changing button type `submit` to `button`.
 Check the working snippet.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchbutton').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    displayHotels();
  });
});

function displayHotels() {
  var location = $('#searchbar');
  location.focus();
  if (location.val() != "") {
    $('.scrolling-box').empty();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="firstBar">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="searchbar">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchbutton">Search</button>
  </form>

  <div class="scrolling-box">
    <img src="review1.jpg" alt="review1">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```